# how to export data from blobstorage adls to sharepoint using adf dataflow activity or copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

how to export data fro blob storage adls to share point using pipelines in adf through data flow activity or copy activity

have a CSV file stored in blob storage. The goal is to move this file into a Sharepoint site and set some metadata. What would be the best way to do this? The client does not want us to use Power Automate or Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ADF doesnt have out of box feature with Sharepoint/ REST as a sink.
So you cannot copy data into sharepoint directly via ADF.
You would need other offerings like Logic app, Azure function, Azure batch etc for that purpose.

Similar thread :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287890/how-to-share-upload-file-to-sharepoint-from-azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287480/how-can-i-migrate-from-azure-blob-storage-to-share